# Difference between bash $HOSTNAME and tcsh/zsh $HOST

Tags: bash, zsh, history, hostname

Is there any difference between `bash`'s `$HOSTNAME` and `zsh`'s `$HOST`?

If no, is there a historical reason for `bash` to chose the `$HOSTNAME` variable when `tcsh` and `zsh` use `$HOST`?

Comment: FWIW, $HOSTNAME was added to bash in 2.0 released in December 1996. Changelog says it was implemented on 1995-08-01. $HOST was added to zsh-2.0 released in 1991. It was already in tcsh in 1987. I can only assume the bash authors thought HOSTNAME was a better name than HOST, and I'd tend to agree (especially considering bash like tcsh (but not zsh) also has $HOSTTYPE), though the difference is unfortunate from a portability PoV.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Make this an answer and I'll salute it :)

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer, namely on the contents of the variables:

The values of all variables come from a call to [`gethostname(2)`](https://manned.org/gethostname):

- `tcsh` [sh.c: `main()`](https://github.com/tcsh-org/tcsh/blob/4173d9bd80ad1e2c63bee5d3575a4d5e679a41a0/sh.c#L684) Default: `unknown`.
- `bash` [shell.c: `shell_initialize()`](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/d233b485e83c3a784b803fb894280773f16f2deb/shell.c#L1867). Default: `??host??`
- `zsh` [param.c: `createparamtable()`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/c6a85163619ed1cee89ab047a0d98108ed46828d/Src/params.c#L840)

The default values are:

- `tcsh`: `unknown`.
- `bash`: `??host??`
- `zsh`: (null)

Interestingly, `zsh` doesn't check the return value!

Comment: You may want to report it as  a bug  to zsh-workers@zsh.org (though I'm not sure how you'd get `gethostname()` not to return a hostname in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

[`$HOSTNAME` was added to bash in 2.0 released in December 1996](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gnu.announce/L63J8S5dhOg/B5P9JbPnBw0J).

Changelog says it was implemented on 1995-08-01.

[`$HOST` was added to zsh-2.0 released in 1991](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.sources.misc/WA4e1Tkuzfo/P2nBO0TJKS0J).

[It was already in `tcsh` in 1987](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.sources.unix/v-q1qRVIpi4/TbAvM_gFD-gJ).

I can only assume the `bash` authors thought HOSTNAME was a better name than HOST, and I can see their point considering that `bash` also had a `$HOSTTYPE` variable (like `tcsh`) itself added much earlier in bash 1.05 in 1990.

`$HOSTTYPE` itself seems to have a more contorted history.

In tcsh 6.05 (June 1994) release notes, you see:

> - $HOSTTYPE is going away. New variables $OSTYPE, $MACHTYPE, $VENDOR similar to the gnu ones.

Those removing the ambiguity as to what *type* we were talking about along with `HOST` from the variable name.

However, `$HOSTTYPE` never went  away in the end in `tcsh`.

`bash` 1.14.0 in June 1994 introduced `$OSTYPE`, but `$MACHTYPE` was not added before 2.0, and `$VENDOR` never made it to `bash`, so I'm not sure what *gnu ones* above refers to.

`zsh` also had `$HOSTTYPE` initially but it was removed there, replaced in zsh-2.6-beta's in 1995 with `$OSTYPE`, `$MACHTYPE` and `$VENDOR`.

In any case, looking here on a Ubuntu GNU/Linux system running on a laptop amd64 PC, values of those variables differ widely between shells, and it looks like their semantics on `bash` has varied significantly between versions as well.

You'll notice that `bash` also decided to depart from `tcsh`/`zsh` prompt expansion where the hostname was `%M` (`%m` for the part before the first dot) and chose `\h` instead (as the equivalent of `%m`).